# How to an apex:tab onClick with a controller instead of javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
Use the onclick with some method in the controller   
 <apex:tab label="AppConfig" name="AppConfig" id="AppConfig" onclick="onClickAppConfig()">


Controller
       public void onClick(){
        //Do domething
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `apex:actionFunction` to call your controller method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a method from controller instead of javascript, you can use **apex:actionFunction**.

```
<apex:outputpanel id="myTab">
    <apex:tab label="AppConfig" name="AppConfig" id="AppConfig" onclick="onClickAppConfig()" />
<apex:outputpanel>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!apexMethod}" name="onClickAppConfig" rerender="myTab">
<!-- add any parameters if you want -->
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Apex controller:

```
public class Controller_name{

   public void apexMethod(){
    //logic
   }
}
```

Refer this link for [Apex Action function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

Comment: So as soon as I click the tab, I want to call a method in the controller. Would this also work with the actionFunction method?

Comment: Yes, it will work

Comment: @KushPatel Is it working for you? Let me know

Comment: You can add the function anywhere in the VF page and just call it using onclick.

Comment: Would I be able to use the actionsupport instead?

Comment: Yes you can also use actionSupport but then you won't be able to pass the parameters.